# Received the "Mortarboard" badge due to Serial Voting. Can this badge be removed please?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, serial-voting, badge-tracking

The system identified and reversed a surge of up-votes between 07:53 to 07:58 and a second surge from 08:16 to 08:18 on 12/23/15. Overall I gained a total of 140 reputation from this mysterious 'benefactor'. Then the system corrected the [Serial Voting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) at [03:00 on 12/24/15](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/144533/blaze?tab=reputation) to give -140 reputation.

While the system was able to detect (and correct) the serial voting, 3 days later I am still left with a badge that I did not earn or deserve.

So I would like to know if it's possible to revoke this badge that I was wrongfully rewarded since I don't want badges, reputation or anything else for that matter in my possession unless I earn them legitimately by myself.

Now, to my serial up-voter; If you're reading this I would like you to know that while I acknowledge your kind thoughts:

> Intentionally voting merely to reduce or inflate another user's
>   reputation is considered [abuse](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

Moderators; Could you please remove this "Mortarboard" badge?

Thank you.

Regards,

BLAZE.

Comment: *We* couldn't. But we were able to poke somebody who could. It's removed now. Good luck getting it.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you; that means a lot. I appreciate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This badge is not revoked automatically. See [Mortarboard badge is being gamed too many times. Maybe time for auto revoke?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181312/mortarboard-badge-is-being-gamed-too-many-times-maybe-time-for-auto-revoke) for a feature request for this to happen.

However, somebody at SE could remove it manually. Possibly somebody will see this or the moderators will escalate it for you. If neither happens soon, you could write to SE see "contact us" at the end of the page.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer, I really hope that it can be removed, I just doesn't 'feel' right owning it.

Comment: Upon inquiring whether it would be much work to do so, a friendly CM removed the badge.